# What is difference between TO_CHAR and TO_DATE

Tags: sql

I'm running two queries

1. `select TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS PM') from dual;`
   It displays date with exact time.
2. `select TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS PM') from dual;`
   It displays date with default time 12:00:00 AM.

I do not understand `TO_CHAR` and `TO_DATE` usage. How to display **date** with **exact** time by using **TO_DATE**

Comment: Tag dbms used, those are product specific functions.

Comment: `TO_DATE()` converts a `varchar` to a `date`. It makes no sense whatsoever to call it on a value that is *already*  a date.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what about if you want to change a date format?

Comment: Then you want to convert a `date` to  a `varchar` so you need `to_char()`. **Never**, ever (really: never) call `to_date()` on a `date` value.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Really? why?.. good to know

Comment: Possible duplicate of [to\_char and to\_date are returning different output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16796350/to-char-and-to-date-are-returning-different-output)

Answer (score 1):

`to_char` function is used to convert the given data into
character....

```
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy') FROM dual;

TO_CHAR(SY
------------------
04/04/2012
```

`to_date` is used to convert the given data into date data
formate data type....

eg: `to_date('070903', 'MMDDYY'`) would return a date value
of July 9, 2003.

Reference: [Interview Question](http://www.allinterview.com/showanswers/10844/what-is-the-difference-between-to-char-and-to-date-functions.html)